# Show that A is an event

Tags: real-analysis, probability

Let $X_n$ be a sequence of random variables on a probability space $(\Omega, F, P)$. Let's define:
$$A=\{ w \in \Omega: \lim_{n \to \infty} X_n(w) \space   \text{exists}\} .$$

Now, I need to show that A is an event, in other words that A is in the $\sigma$-algebra F. What would be the classical approach to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sequence $(X_n(\omega))_n$ has a limit iff it is a Cauchy sequence, so:

$$A=\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}\bigcap_{r=k}^{\infty}\bigcap_{s=k}^{\infty}\left\{\omega\in\Omega: \left|X_{r}\left(\omega\right)-X_{s}\left(\omega\right)\right|<n^{-1}\right\}$$

Comment: How do we know that $\{ω∈Ω:|Xr(ω)−Xs(ω)|<\frac{1}{n}\}$ is measurable?

Comment: @L.G If $X_r$ and $X_s$ are random variables then it can be shown that also $|X_r-X_s|$ is a random variable (and consequently the mentioned set is measurable).

Answer (score 1):

For any $\omega\in\Omega$, $\{X_n(\omega)\}$ is a sequence of real numbers, so the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}X_n(\omega)$ exists if and only if $\{X_n(\omega)\}$ is a Cauchy sequence. That is, for all positive integers $n$, there exists a positive integer $k$ such that $r\geqslant s\geqslant k$ implies
$$|X_r(\omega)-X_s(\omega)|<n^{-1}. $$
From there you can write $A$ as a measurable set as in @drhab's answer.

Comment: How do we know that $\{ω∈Ω:|Xr(ω)−Xs(ω)|<\frac{1}{n}\}$ is measurable?

Comment: $X_r$ and $X_s$ are random variables, so $|X_r(\omega)-X_s(\omega)|$ is a random variable.